# How's a semialgebra actually a "semi"-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

According to the definitions that I'm familiar with, a `semialgebra` of a set $X$ defined as a collection $S
\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ , such that:

1. $\emptyset,X\in S$
2. for every $A,B \in S$ it also holds that $A\cap B\in S$.
3. for every $A,B \in S$ , we have $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^{n}\subset S$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}C_i = A\setminus B$ and  $C_i\cap C_j =\emptyset$ for every $i\neq j $.

The defintion I have for `algebra` is as follows - $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal {P} (X)$ , such that:
1. $X\in \mathcal{A}$
2. same as (2) for `semialgebra`.
3. for each $A\in \mathcal A$ we have also $A^c \in \mathcal A$

**My question:**
 To my understanding, an `Algebra` is not necessarily a `semialgebra` , and so I wonder why whould one call it "semi" - algebra?

Comment: Corrected 3, $AB$ to $A \setminus B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an algebra, if $A,B \in \mathcal A$, then $A \setminus B \in \mathcal A$ since $A \setminus B = A \cap B^c$.  So we may take $n=1$ and $C_1 = A \setminus B$ to get the semialgebra property.